# Evaluating $\int_0^{\sqrt{3}}{\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}}\,dx$

Tags: integration

Could someone please show me how to evaluate this integral (maybe doing all the steps)?
$$\int_0^{\sqrt{3}}{\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}}\,dx$$
I prefer if you avoid to follow the same method used by WolframAlpha (with $\csc$, $\sec$ ecc).
This is what I tried 'till now:

1. Substitution with $\sqrt{1+x^2} = u$ I obtained:
   $$\int{\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}}\,du = \int{\frac{u^2}{u^2-1}}\,du$$
   But not knowing how to continue, I tried another substitution with $u^2 - 1 = s$ and I obtained:
   $$\int{\frac{s+1}{s} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{s+1}} }\,ds = \frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{s+1}{s\sqrt{s+1}}}\,ds$$
   But, again, not knowing how to continue I decided to ask here.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Try http://wolframalpha.com for evaluating integrals. It even shows a step-by-step-solution!

Comment: i guess there is a typo in the integral somewhere. $$\int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\,dx>\int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx =+\infty.$$

Comment: @vesszabo: i was typing the same thing, but 2 minutes after you. I just noticed that. :-)  I'll delete my post.

Comment: It's good to notice that depending on integration interval one may use a nice trick that involves the inverse of the integrand that could be direclty integrated.

Comment: @Chris Could you show me how? It seems interesting :)

Comment: @unNaturhal: look at vesszabo's comment. I think that integration interval is wrong, or?

Comment: @Chris, No, it's right. It was an exam exercise that I'm doing to have practice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $u \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}$ we have
$$
\frac{u^2}{u^2-1}=\frac{u^2-1+1}{u^2-1}=1+\frac{1}{u^2-1}
=1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1}\right),
$$
and so
$$
\int\frac{u^2}{u^2-1}du=\int\left[1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1}\right)\right]du=u+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{u-1}{u+1}\right| +C.
$$

Comment: Oh.. now it's clear! I could not understand how to obtain the partial fractions.. Thank you :)

Comment: Ehm.. I'm sorry but.. could you tell me how you obtained $1+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1})$? I'm trying, but I can't find a simple ad immediate way..

Comment: This is known as the method of partial fractions.  Any calculus textbook should have an explanation (at least for cases like this with linear factors).

Comment: $$\frac{1}{u^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{u+1-(u-1)}{u^2-1}=...$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{u^2}{u^2-1}=1+\frac12\frac1{u-1}-\frac12\frac1{u+1}$$

Comment: WA said the da same thing.. but I haven't immediately understand how to get this result..

Comment: First get rid of the $1$, then decompose $1/(u^2-1)=1/((u-1)(u+1))$ into a linear combination of the simple fractions $1/(u\pm1)$.

Comment: $\frac{u^2}{u^2-1} = \frac{u^2-1+1}{u^2-1} = 1 + \frac{1}{u^2-1} $. Then do partial fraction. This is the standard trick, called adding $0$.

Comment: I'm sorry... could you tell me if there is a formula to do the partial fraction?

Comment: There is. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction#Procedure).

Answer (score 1):

Your first substitution was good, but the next one kind of got away from the solution. After you reach $\displaystyle\int \frac{u^2}{u^2-1} du$ apply partial fractions.